# Check occurrence of element in string with Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have strings and some of them may contain

```
:
```

or

```
=
```

I would like to find all cases, where these symbols occurs, but only once(!).

I wrote this code, which works, but would like to solve with Regex expression

```js
function find(stringToCheck: string): string {
    return stringToCheck.includes(':') &&
        stringToCheck.split(':').length - 1 === 1
        ? ':'
        : stringToCheck.includes('=') && stringToCheck.split('=').length - 1 === 1
        ? '='
        : '';
}
```

Comment: So is each char, `:` and `=`, is allowed to exist once in the string? Or are you saying that only one of those chars is a allowed to exist in the string and it can only exist once?

Comment: Or are you saying that if `:` exists only once then `=` can exist multiple times? and vice versa...

Comment: Exactly, only one of those chars is a allowed to exist in the string and it can only exist once. If : exist, = should not exist at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is searched for matches with `:` or `=` which are then stored as a [RegExp match array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). The length of this array then matches how many instances of the string were found.

Where the RexExp objects are created the flag `"g"` is used to find all matches, rather than just the first one.

```js
function find (stringToTest) {
  const a = stringToTest.match(new RegExp(":", "g"));
  const b = stringToTest.match(new RegExp("=", "g"));
  if (a?.length > 1 || b?.length > 1) return true;
  return false;
}

console.log(find("hello:world=")); // false
console.log(find("hello world")); // false
console.log(find("hello world====")); // true
```

Comment: it helps a lot, thank you, but I need to return true only if it occurs once, so by testing the third case, the function should return false

Comment: Edited to match your use case - hope this is good.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function find (stringToCheck)
{
  return (/^[^:]*:[^:]*$/.test(stringToCheck) && /^[^=]*=?[^=]*$/.test(stringToCheck))||(/^[^:]*:?[^:]*$/.test(stringToCheck) && /^[^=]*=[^=]*$/.test(stringToCheck));
}

console.log(find("iron:man"));
console.log(find("iron=man"));
console.log(find("iron::man"));
console.log(find("iron==man"));
console.log(find("ironman"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
^[^:=]*[:=][^:=]*$
```

```js
function checkString(str){
    return /^[^:=]*[:=][^:=]*$/.test(str);
}

console.log(checkString('Neither'));
console.log(checkString('One equal ='));
console.log(checkString('One colon :'));
console.log(checkString('colon equal :='));
console.log(checkString('Multiple = equal ='));
console.log(checkString('Multiple : colon :'));
console.log(checkString('Multiple = both : col=on :'));
```